# Setting text to TextView from EditText element shows blank

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I have an EditText field for name field and a button. When I type a name in the field and press the button. It should show "Hi, " + value of EditText field.

My solution is to getText().toString() on the EditText object and passed it to a string variable. But it returns "" whenever I use it to setText().

I used this instead and it works but i'm confused what's the difference ? nametext.setText("Hi,nametext.getText().toString());

```
Button btn_show;
EditText nametext;
String input_msg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nametext = findViewById(R.id.name_text);
    input_msg = nametext.getText().toString();

    btn_show = findViewById(R.id.hi);

    btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nametext.setText("Hi, " + input_msg);  // this returns ""

        /* when i use nametext.getText().toString() in place of input_msg
        /* it returns the string I typed in the edittext. What's the 
        /* difference?
        /* nametext.setText("Hi,nametext.getText().toString()); // returns the actual string I typed in the edittext field

        }
    });
}
```

nametext.setText("Hi,nametext.getText().toString()); // returns the actual string typed in the field

nametext.setText("Hi, " + input_msg); // returns ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello there you are doing it in a right way just a little mistake that you are calling `getText()` before **Click**.

```
btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        input_msg = nametext.getText().toString();
        nametext.setText("Hi, " + input_msg); 
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is a difference is that when you populate `input_msg`, the value is still empty. When you click the button after the string is the view is populated, `input_msg` hasn't changed.

So what you need to do is to get the value only when the button is clicked:

```
btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        nametext.setText("Hi, " + nametext.getText().toString()); 
    }
});
```

And if you want to use Java 8, it's even simpler:

```
btn_show.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> nametext.setText("Hi, " + nametext.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: thanks Doron! will consider that Java 8 syntax too.